# Hiding NSIS Dialog

Tags: nsis

I am new to NSIS so bear with me:

I am using NSIS (legacy code...) for making sure that .NET is installed before launching a .NET application.

If it is not installed, I am installing it for the user, but I would prefer getting user's approval before playing hooky with his system.

I was able to display the message to the user:

[image]

using this code:

```
WriteIniStr $MissingItemsIniFilename 'Field 2' 'State' '$R2'
WriteIniStr $MissingItemsIniFilename 'Settings' 'CancelEnabled' 1


InstallOptions::Dialog $MissingItemsIniFilename
Pop $1 ;get button action
```

my problem is that after user clicks `Next` the "dialog" is not closing and shows:

[image]

So my question is, How can I close the dialog?

Extra information:
I am using InstallOptions for showing the dialog.
I looked into nsDialogs but could not find there a solution that worked for me (might be due to lack of experience in NSIS).

Please let me know if any other information is required...

Comment: Are you calling ExecWait right after the dialog function returns?

Comment: @Anders few rows later a functions that executes the `ExecWait` is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the entire installer you can do:

```
HideWindow
ExecWait ...
BringToFront
```

otherwise you should probably move that ExecWait to a Section...